# curl sending null data on POST request to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to POST data through curl windows 64 bits onto a asp.net web api(using C#) .
However every tim i do so, the control passes to the HttpPost method however the values of the accepting parameter remains null.
This works without curl on using url on browser..so no problem with database.

My curl syntax is:

```
curl -X POST 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '[{"Id":"44","Name":"Abc","Category":"xyz","Price":"98"}]' "http://example.com/Post/Products"
```

My server side code of web api is

```
[ActionName("Default Action")]
[Route("Post/Products")]
[AcceptVerbs("Get"), HttpPost]
public List<ProductDetails> PostProduct([FromBody] List<ProductDetails>  pro)
{
    // IEnumerable<string> headerValues = Request.Headers.GetValues("MyCustomID");
    // var ide = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
    // int id=Convert.ToInt16(pro.Id);
    // int Pric = Convert.ToInt16(Pricc);
    con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\mydatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand ss = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Table] values ("+pro[0].Id+",'"+pro[0].Name+"','"+pro[0].Category+"',"+pro[0].Price+")", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr2 = ss.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand ("select * from [Table]",con); 
    SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr1.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            product1.Add(new ProductDetails() { Id = int.Parse(dr1[0].ToString()), Name = dr1[1].ToString(), Category = dr1[2].ToString(), Price = int.Parse(dr1[3].ToString()) });
        }
    }
    con.Close();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // var item = new pro { Id = id, Name = Nam, Category = Cate, Price = Pric };
        // products.Add(item);
        HttpResponseMessage response =Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, product1);
        // response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi1", new { id=item.Id }));               
    }
    return product1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried indicating charset? e.g. application/json; charset=utf-8  I'm unfamiliar with curl.  Can you get something like Fiddler in between curl and the service to see exactly what is getting sent in?  Have you tried posting exactly the same content using Fiddler?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to how the quotes are handled by `cmd.exe` when using curl on Windows.

Change the command to use only double quotes and escape all of the ones in your JSON data.

```
curl -X POST "Content-Type:application/json" --data "[{\"Id\":\"44\",\"Name\":\"Abc\",\"Category\":\"xyz\",\"Price\":\"98\"}]" "http://example.com/Post/Products"
```